# Duplicate value at last date of month to all previous dates in that month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, duplicates

[This is how the data looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBEJU.png)

PERMNO is the ticker for different stocks. I want to extract the RET value for each stock at the last date in each month and duplicate it to the other dates in that month. Say RET = 0.01 for PERMNO 10006 30.06.1928, then all RET values from 01.06.1928-30.06.1928 should show 0.01 as well. This is to be done for all dates and all stocks. I have tried with groupby, loops and dateranges, but run into problems..

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: so what have you tried? into which specific problem did you run? can you come up with a [mre] (please add sample data as text, not image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert to datetimes ans sorting and then use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['PERMNO','Date'])
df['new'] = df.groupby(['PERMNO', df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month])['RET'].transform('last')
```